# Save as Content-Disposition filename in Explore 11

Tags: java, pdf, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 is ignoring my filename. When I try to "Save As" the archive name don't match with what I put on "filename=". Its getting from URL. Why others browsers works just fine? What do I have to do?

```
    String szFilename = "archive.pdf";
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length - nBufferStart);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + szFilename);
```

Comment: IE is pretty infamous for not following a lot of the standards

Comment: True, it's not the first time that I get in a issue with IE. Requires special treatment all  the time

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> String szFilename = "archive.pdf";
> response.setContentType("application/pdf");
> response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length - nBufferStart);
> response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + szFilename);
> ```

I have created a sample using the similar code, it seems that your code works well in IE 11. Please try to put the file name in double quotes, like this(it also works well in IE11 browser):

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + szFilename + "\"");
```

Comment: Try to use `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + szFilename + "\"");`